# Can I close avgrund jquery element from outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I use avgrund jquery element for legal disclaimer, before I move the user to another *blank* page. But I need to close the avgrund before I pop up the new window. I couldn't find a way to close the avgrund from outside function. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: can you just call CloseDialog() ?

Answer (score 1):

Just played around this plugin today too. And search for while seems there is no pre-set function to customize closing action. 
But if you take a look at the source code, it says:

```
body = $('body'),
body.append('<div class="avgrund-overlay ' + options.overlayClass + '"></div>');
```

So try to add an removing class action as a close function, such as:

```
function closeAvgrund(){
            $('body').removeClass("avgrund-active");
            $('body').removeClass("avgrund-overlay");
}
```

It works on local here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
yourAvgrundElement.deactivate();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way that I can see (this API is weird), but if you call it with `closeByDocument: true` (the default), you can trigger a click on the overlay element it creates:

```
$('.avgrund-overlay').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
function closeDialog() {
   Avgrund.hide();
}
```

Check out the source here: https://github.com/hakimel/Avgrund/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a button with the 'avgrund-close' class and then redirect, that's how I did it.